# Winforms Without Database: Differnt Forms Using Same Stateful Class

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, design-patterns, state

I'm developing a small utility Winforms application. It simply transforms a file which is loaded to memory. There is no database.

There is a stateful class which represents that file. It is basically the application's data source in lieu of a database. The data in this class needs to be read/modified by several different forms in the application.

How should I structure this application to ensure the forms can easily communicate with that class. Could my main form simply keep passing the object to its child forms or is that bad practice? Are there better alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an instance of your application state object to child forms is acceptable.

Or, you could write your state class using the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), so that it is instantiated once (and only once).

```
public class MyState
{
    // private constructor to stop others from instantiating the object
    private MyState()  { }

    private static MyState instance;

    public static MyState Instance
    {
        get 
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new MyState();
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    // Insert the class' methods/properties here as public, non-static
}
```

You could also use a [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) library to supply your state class to child forms. I like [Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac), but there are many others.

Ultimately, the best practice is to write code that fits the needs of your application.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is just to have on Static Accessor class that provides access to the class for your whole app, like this:

```
public static class AppObjects
{
    private static MyClass _myClass;

    public static GetMyClass()
    {
        if(_myClass == null)
        {
            //Init/Load Object
        }
        return _myClass
    }
}
```

That said, it isn't horrendous to have the Parent Form pass the object to it's Child Forms. You only need to use a more complex solution if you expect something relevant (like your UI structure, or the number of objects needed) to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple instance repository. The logic of this is that you can retrieve an install from the collection, you should also provide an add method to add an instance.

Sample would be

```
        private List<object> _instanceRepo;

    public TInstance Retrieve<TInstance>()
    {
        TInstance response = default(TInstance);
        object retrieved = _instanceRepo.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TInstance));
        if (retrieved == null)
            Console.WriteLine("retrieved object was null.");
        else
            response = (TInstance)retrieved;

        return response;
    }
```

or create a singleton, this is achieved by making a static property of the class that exposes a single instance.

Read factory here: [Factory](http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory)
Read singleton here: [Singleton](http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton)

Comment: Perhaps update your code sample to throw an exception or something rather than `Console.WriteLine`, as the OP is using `WinForms`

Comment: @rhughes well, it's not meant to be copy pasted anyway :D, made it like that so the OP gets to do something rather than the common copy pasta.